# Getting System.OutOfMemoryException in C# while fetching data from oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to reprocess 3.5 million data from database. We are using oracle pl/sql 11g. And I tried to fetch 1000 rows per batch for reprocessing. But after processing 42000 rows it throws out of memory exception.
This is my code

```
internal void dataReprocessor(int rowCount)
{

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    int MaxProcessid = AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetMaxProcessId();
    startCount=AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetErrorCount();
    ShowStatus("Max. processid:" + MaxProcessid);
    ShowStatus("Fetching " + rowCount + " rows....");
    do
    {

        dataTable.Clear();
        dataTable = AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetHundreadrows(rowCount, MaxProcessid);
         if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
         {


             for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                int error = 0;
                mainId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["MAINID"]);
                itemId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["ITEMID"]);
                siteid = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["SITE_ID"]);
                equipmentId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["EQUIPMENT_TYPE"]);
                qrCode = dataTable.Rows[i]["QRCODE"].ToString();
                string equipmentname = AssetProcessorDbHandler.Getequipmentname(equipmentId);
                error = DbHandler.CheckQRCofEquipment(siteid, equipmentId, itemId, qrCode,ref assetStatus);
                if (error == 1)//Not available in iMapp.
                {
                    MESSAGE=string.Concat("QRCode ",qrCode," for ",equipmentname," is not available in iMapp!");
                    AssetProcessorDbHandler.UpdateSMSintoQRCtable(itemId, MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (error == 2)//Not available in that site.
                {
                    int mappedsite = AssetProcessorDbHandler.Getmappedsiteid(qrCode);
                    MESSAGE = string.Concat("QRCode ", qrCode, " for ", equipmentname, " is mapped with site IN-", mappedsite);
                    AssetProcessorDbHandler.UpdateSMSintoQRCtable(itemId,MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (assetStatus == 1)//Equipment was in Finance verifiaction pending
                {
                    MESSAGE = string.Concat("Finance verification pending of ", equipmentname, " for site IN-", siteid, " in iMapp. Please contact corporate finance team.");
                    AssetProcessorDbHandler.UpdateSMSintoQRCtable(itemId, MESSAGE);
                }
                 AssetProcessorDbHandler.UpdateReprocessed(MaxProcessid + 1, itemId);
            }
        }
    } while (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0);

    ShowStatus("--Completed.--");
    finalCount = AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetErrorCount();
    ShowStatus(startCount + " ROWS PROCESSED.");
    ShowStatus(finalCount + " ROWS ARE STILL ON ERROR.");

}
```

Anybody help me out please? The issue is escalating.

Comment: Did you ever try to dispose the data table and create it from scratch each time?

Comment: Your code uses custom libraries, which makes very difficult for folks out here to provide concrete advice. You should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have your tried doing the same using a [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69(v=vs.110).aspx). This is what I use when I have to process large number of rows in an efficient manner. This is what the Oracle driver would use behind the screen to populate the `DataTable`

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue while we are always processing millions of records per day.

The problem is we had too many connections open to oracle database and did not close and dispose the objects well.

It is better to use the bellow snippet while interacting with oracle database.

```
using(var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
      oracleConnection.Open()
      //do your stuff here.

}
```

Comment: Yeah - there's some talk about this in the Oracle .NET Data Provider documentation.  I remember having to deal with this several years ago.

Comment: @MetalMikester The problem is that you have to call dispose each time you are opening a connection to oracle database. the above method always calls dispose.

Comment: Correct.  We were not doing that originally - well, not "always", so we had the occasional hiccup.  A sprint code review/refactoring got rid of the problem before it got nasty.

Comment: Hi @Bewar Salah . We are using our own framework. So these core parts already defined and cannot be edited.

Comment: @Kannan you have to replace the framework or redesign it. you can only change the part that the connection is being opened then call dispose use **using**.

Answer (score 0):

You are never disposing your datatables. Stay with one datatable per loop and dispose it properly.

This part:

```
do
{

    dataTable.Clear();
    dataTable = AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetHundreadrows(rowCount, MaxProcessid);
     if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
```

Should read:

```
while(true)
{
    using(var dataTable = AssetProcessorDbHandler.GetHundreadrows(rowCount, MaxProcessid))
    {
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0) break;
```

Comment: Hi @nvoigt thanks for the answer. But the memory utilization is same.

Comment: @Kannan Well, that's the only thing you could improve. Maybe the framework you are using is buggy and leaking? Without any hint what `AssetProcessorDbHandler` looks like, it's unlikely you will get help here.

Comment: `internal DataTable GetAssetCount(int siteid, int assetid)
        {
            string query = string.Concat("SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM   V2_SITE_ASSET WHERE SITEID=", siteid, " AND ASSETID=", assetid);
            DataTable checkeQRCinSiteOrNot = new DataTable();
            Select(query, checkeQRCinSiteOrNot);
            return checkeQRCinSiteOrNot;
        }`



This is a method in `AssetProcessorDbHandler` and also contains may other methods like same structure

Comment: @Kannan You should add that to your question.

Comment: @Kannan Sorry, but the interface of your framework *and* it's internal implementation is severely lacking. You need to get a better framework or a better educated framework writer. Maybe both.

Comment: @Kannan What does the `Select` method look like?

Comment: @nvoigt No idea, because they are hidden from ours. They are not exposing any code behind our framework.

Comment: @Kannan Then I guess you will need to send your sample to your framework writers as a bug report.